# Angular ui-select error: 404 (Failed to load template)

Tags: angularjs, ui-select2, angularjs-select2

Anyone having issue using [angular-ui-select](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select)?

Getting this error

```
GET http://localhost/select2/select.tpl.html 404 (Not Found) angular.js:8539
Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: select2/select.tpl.html
```

From the documentation - i just needed to reference select.js and select.css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the select.css and select.js files from the /[dist](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/tree/master/dist) directory instead of the files from the /[src](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/tree/master/src) directory.

Answer (score 0):

You need templates as well - look into src folder. There are 3 themes.

When you include select into your page you specify which one you want to use:

```
<ui-select ng-model="boo.selected" theme="resources/templates/select2" ng-disabled="disabled">
```

Here above I put path to templates

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because the template in the error message is not loaded into the templateCache. You are probably using a version of select.js that doesn't contain the templates.

*Also you will find that not every template design has been made for every select type. Eg. there are no Selectize templates for multiselect, that can also cause similar errors.*

If you take a look at the end of the [select.js source](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/blob/master/dist/select.js) you will see how you can load the templates or even define your own template.

In your case:

```
angular.module("ui.select").run(["$templateCache", function($templateCache){
    $templateCache.put("select2/select.tpl.html","<div class=\"ui-select-container select2 select2-container\" ng-class=\"{\'select2-container-active select2-dropdown-open open\': $select.open,\n \'select2-container-disabled\': $select.disabled,\n \'select2-container-active\': $select.focus, \n \'select2-allowclear\': $select.allowClear && !$select.isEmpty()}\"><div class=\"ui-select-match\"></div><div class=\"select2-drop select2-with-searchbox select2-drop-active\" ng-class=\"{\'select2-display-none\': !$select.open}\"><div class=\"select2-search\" ng-show=\"$select.searchEnabled\"><input type=\"text\" autocomplete=\"off\" autocorrect=\"off\" autocapitalize=\"off\" spellcheck=\"false\" class=\"ui-select-search select2-input\" ng-model=\"$select.search\"></div><div class=\"ui-select-choices\"></div></div></div>");
}]);
```